# Alternative solution for PHP/SQL max array size problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, memory

I have a table bundled among 100 databases in MYSQL (i.e. 1st x rows of the table in database_1, 2nd x rows of the table in database_2, ... , last x rows of the table in database_100)

Each table has a row whenever a user visits a friend for a game.
The columns are iuin, logtime, beuin.
iuin is the user id of the visitor.
beuin is the user id of the friend who was visited. 
logtime is when the visit was made.

I would like to find the # of distinct friends who were visited during a week.
There is roughly 300k distinct users who are visited per day.

However, when I extended my code to calculate for a week, I ran out of memory.
My code basically does an SQL query using SELECT DISTINCT beuin for a selected week for the table in each database. I store all the beuin in an array if it's not already stored (so I count distinct friends who were visited), and return the size of the array at the end.

FYI, I can't edit the database around such as joining all the tables in different databases into one table.

Is there any alternative ways i can do this?
Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of storing it in an array and getting the array size?

Comment: so I only count distinct users. Ideally, the tables are not bundled into different databases, so I can just do SELECT DISTINCT beuin and just return mysql_num_rows().

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything about your without the one. But I think you can solve this problem using mysql. My quick solution:

1. Create table - CREATE table if not exist users_ids(user_id INT NOT NULL DEAULT 0 PRIMARY KEY(UNIQUE)); in the first db
2. Truncate users_ids
3. Run 100 queries like INSERT IGNORE INTO db1.users_ids select distinct user_id from db1.table1;
4. Select count(*) from users_ids;